# How do I delete a string until I encounter a certain character in Python?

Tags: python, string

I've got a really long file which has some random GPS gibberish in it, and I want to remove it. Basically, everything is in , but sometimes you get stuff like this:

`<gibberish <data data>` - multiple open brackets, without closing. The problem is that the gibberish is of varying length. How do I find and replace the gibberish part? - in this example, the `"<gibberish "` ? I was thinking this might be done in python, but any language would do.

Comment: An input with expected output example would be helpful.

Comment: Could you add a little context? Give us your starting data and your anticipated result.

[Edit] - Or what Padraic Cunningham just said..

Comment: How do you identify the "gibberish" there?

Comment: Here's an example:

<E,104,55793,329,G858B,0   48800.780  48805.424 08:37:47.55 01/08/26   0>

<E,104,56294,334,G858B,0   48800.690<E,104,56392,335,G858B,0   48800.638  48805.410 08:37:48.15 01/08/26   0>

The first line is ok, the second line opens another bracket before the first one is closed, and I want to delete everything that's before it, so the expected outcome would be:

<E,104,55793,329,G858B,0   48800.780  48805.424 08:37:47.55 01/08/26   0>

<E,104,56392,335,G858B,0   48800.638  48805.410 08:37:48.15 01/08/26   0>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.sub` function.

```
>>> s = '<E,104,55793,329,G858B,0 48800.780 48805.424 08:37:47.55 01/08/26 0> <E,104,56294,334,G858B,0 48800.690<E,104,56392,335,G858B,0 48800.638 48805.410 08:37:48.15 01/08/26 0>'
>>> re.sub(r'<[^<>]*<', r'<', s)
'<E,104,55793,329,G858B,0 48800.780 48805.424 08:37:47.55 01/08/26 0> <E,104,56392,335,G858B,0 48800.638 48805.410 08:37:48.15 01/08/26 0>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty simply by finding the index of the last open bracket, and taking everything from that point on:

```
source = '<E,104,56294,334,G858B,0 48800.690<E,104,56392,335,G858B,0 48800.638 48805.410 08:37:48.15 01/08/26 0>'
data = source[source.rfind('<'):]
```